# Pythonic way to transform a 2d array into a RGB image, using dictionaries

Tags: python, image, numpy

Say I have a 2d Matrix like

```
[[80 80 80]
 [ 0  50  0]
 [ 0  0  50]
 [ 0  50  0]
 [ 30  30  30]]
```

and I have a dictionary like

```
color_dict = {
  80: (255,255,0),
  50: (255,0,0),
  30: (0,0,255)
}
```

I would like to get an BGR image (very small in this case, but image anyway) that is the reflection of the matrix based on the color assigned to each value by the dictionary.

I can do it using a loop which is my first instinct. But is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Are you thinking of a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

I see two options in this case:

**Option 1: Numpy indexing**

```
# First of all you need to map your random values to a continuous discrete range:
# 0 -> 0, 30 -> 1, 50 -> 2, 80 -> 3, for this you can use basic indexing.

# Now we have an array containing the position of each pixel and his corresponding value
img = np.array([[0,1,2],
                [2,1,0]])
# And another array containing the colormap for each value
val = np.array([[255,255,0],  # -> 0
                [255,0,100],  # -> 1
                [100,0,0]])   # -> 2

# If we index the second array with the first one we obtain a new 3D array, the final image:
res = val.T[:,img]
```

Which looks like this:

```
array([[[250, 255, 100],
        [100, 255, 250]],

       [[250,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0, 250]],

       [[  0, 100,   0],
        [  0, 100,   0]]])
```

**Options 2: Indexed color**

Some image formats support [indexed color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color):

[image]

Where a colormap associate each value with a specific color. So using one of those format will directly solve your problem.

Comment: In the first option img.shape is (2,3) while res.shape=(3,2,3). Shouldn't it be (2,3,3)?

Comment: Don't know how your output should looks like, but if you need a (x,y,3) array then simply use `res = val[img]` instead.